# Кириллицу в hex

Tags: powershell, hex, active-directory

Добрый день. Есть задача преобразовать названия городов написанные кириллицей в HEX формат, но надо преобразовать так как это хочет майкрософ. Потом по созданным hex-ам создам qds файлы для поиска в AD. 
Есть вот такой код

```
  $a = "Хабаровск";
$b = $a.ToCharArray();
Foreach ($element in $b) {$c = $c  + [System.String]::Format("{0:X}" + "0", [System.Convert]::ToUInt32($element))}
$c
```

Но он выдает `4250430043104300440043E04320441043A0` такое значение. А если сохраняю запрос поиска в AD в qds файл, то там в месте где название города указано `250430043104300440043E04320441043A04000005` такое значение, вконце после нолей идет чексумма это понятно. Вроде все одинаково, но что за 4-ка вначале, это hex из длины строки идет , что-ли? в конце идет `hex` из `stringlenght+1`. Не сталкивался никто с такой задачей? Пршу прощения, если слабочитабильно, чет не догоняю как тут отредактировать нормально

Comment: Текст в юникоде, русский язык в UTF-16 вторым байтом имеет 0x04. В первой строке что-то пошло не так. Вторая выглядит более ли менее валидно, с терминатором и магической 5.

Comment: Ааа, у вас какого-то 4 с конца в начало переехала. Да, 36 символов на девять букв...

Comment: ну с 4 разобрался, по итогу просто ее реплэйсом в конец забросил. Мне не понятно одно сейчас, в 250430043104300440043E04320441043A04000005, 5 это хэш чексуммы, но что за 00000 перед этой пятеркой, для слова Хабаровск, получается 5 нолей, если пишу Москва то 4 ноля. При хэшировании названий городов нолей в конце вообще нет, я их добавляю конкатенацией, на подобие того как сохраняет винда. Только от чего зависит количество этих нолей, беру трехсимвольный город получаю 4 ноля, беру 8 символов 4, беру 9 -4 , только в "Хабаровск" получается 5 почему-то. а пишу "хабаровск", то блин 4 ноля получается

Comment: Нуль-терминатор, очевидно.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, Сергей, может ты объяснишь феномен?

Comment: `function ConvertTo-QdsString { param([string]$String) -join ([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($String) | % { $CheckSum = 0 } { $_; $CheckSum = ($CheckSum + $_) % 256 } { 0; 0; $CheckSum } | % ToString X2) } ConvertTo-QdsString Хабаровск`